# How do i run a process in a specific directory?

Tags: debian, cd-command, initrd

In an init.d file i wrote the below. Now i need to make the bin run in a specific directory. How do i tell it which directory to use?

```
mono --debug /path/bin &
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd /my/directory
mono --debug /path/bin &
```

Comment: "cd /my/directory && mono --debug /path/bin &" would be better.

Comment: @symcbean that's true, if you're worried the directory might not exist, your way is better.

Comment: try this without changing the current directory of the shell `/bin/env PWD=/my/directory /path/to/mono --debug /path/bin &`

Comment: @PaulTomblin I would suggest to use the full path to mono, to avoid any ambiguity from any possible mono program/script being present in /my/directory and if the PATH leads to use the current working directory as the source for first lookup.